# Filter changed files view

Tags: gitkraken

Is there a way to filter the changed files view in gitkraken by supplying a filter string?

So for example if I were to enter the string "*.xml", the changed files view would only show .xml files.

Comment: You can do this with GITextensions, and it's free

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to provide a string to filter the changed files view.

The only option to change the shown files is to switch between the path view, showing a list of all files with their full paths, and the tree view, which shows the directory structure of changed files as a tree.

If you look at older commits (not the current changes), you can tick the "View all files" box. This will show all files, and also provide a search box (saying "Filter files"), which will allow you to search for strings like `.xml` in the repositorys state at the selected commit, and filter the files shown accordingly.